# How to append a multiply nested list into and empty one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

I've seen this code in a book:

```
def print_loop(items):
    for i in items: 
        if isinstance(i, list):
            print_loop(i)
        else:
            print(i)
```

What this does is it prints out a multiply nested list. Works perfectly fine with any multiply layered list.

I thought how about if we modify the function so that it simply appends the multiply nested list to an empty list.
Here is how I changed it:

```
def append_loop(items):
    func_items = []

    for i in items: 
        if isinstance(i, list):
            append_loop(i)
        else:
            func_items.append(i)
    return func_items
```

If I have a list like: `items = [1,2,3 [4,5, [6,7]]]`
and try with with my function, all it return is [1,2,3].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `append_loop(i)`, this is returning a flattened list. You have to do something with that, for instance extending `func_items` with it:

```
>>> def append_loop(items):
...   func_items = []
...   for i in items:
...       if isinstance(i, list):
...           func_items.extend(append_loop(i))
...       else:
...           func_items.append(i)
...   return func_items
...
>>> append_loop([1,2,[3,[4,5]]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Otherwise, you could use a `global` list:

```
>>> global_func_items = []
>>> def append_loop2(items):
...   for i in items:
...       if isinstance(i, list):
...           append_loop2(i)
...       else:
...           global_func_items.append(i)
...
>>> append_loop2([1,2,[3,[4,5]]])
>>> print global_func_items
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```